# How can I use supertype in django database model?

Tags: django, database, django-models, django-orm

I have next models in my DB. `Question` represents a question and a poll associated with one, `TextPollQuestion` has a text before the question, `Answer` contains an answer text and link to the question, `UserAnswers` holds user's answers:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, null=True, blank=True)
    user_answers = models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile, through='UserAnswers')

class TextPollQuestion(Question):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=450)

class Answer(models.Model):
    answer_text = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True, blank=True)

class UserAnswers(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=40)
```

With this code I have to create another subtypes of `Answer`, `UserAnswers` and some other models connected to `Question` model to use them with `TextPollQuestion` model, but it obviously violates DRY principle. What should I use in order to link all models to some supertype of `Question` and `TextPollQuestion` and avoid duplicating models?

Comment: I don't think it violates DRY principle. Your questions and answers varies so much, there's not much abstraction in there.

Comment: You need to be careful when defining models: keep in mind that creating a model class doesn't just create the class, but creates an extra database table as well. Your models should be designed with the database schema in mind, not with DRY principles in mind. If necessary you can use abstract models to keep it more DRY.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the title of your question...

Django has 3 main "patterns" for subclassing when writing models.

1. [**Abstract model**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes). Main use of abstract model is to save you some coding time. Say, you have some fiels in several models that are the same. You define a model class that defines this fields and make it abstract. Then you define other model classes, that should contain this fields and make them subclasses of you abstract model. This way the abstract model itself doesn't get a separate DB table, but each subclass (unless it's abstract) gets it's own table with the field defined in abstract model. Follow the link for more details.
2. [**Common model inheritance (Multi-table inheritance)**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance). This is usually used when one model extends the data represented in another model. Say, you have a model defining essential data and need to have model with more details, that are used seldom. I.e. model "Users" with fields "Username", "Password", and model "Profile" with fields "Age", "Gender" for each user. Then you could define "User" model and define "Profile" as it's subclass. This will lead to 2 separate tables being created - "User" and "Profile" and linked via One-To-One relationship implicitly by Django ORM. It's almost the same as if you would define two separate models yourself without inheritance and added "OneToOne" field connecting them.
3. [**Proxy model**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#proxy-models). This one is commonly used when you need to have some special behavior on existing model that differs from behavior already defined for it. This way you have some original model, and then define one more model making it a subclass of original and claiming it to be "proxy". Then you can redefine any behavior on this subclass. This will lead to only one table bieing created in DB for the original model, while to access this table you will be able to use both models.

Remember that every model you define, unless it's "abstract", "unmanaged" or "proxy", will lead to a table being created for it in DB by Django ORM.